# Values are not coming in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html:

```
 <body>
<label>
    Year:
</label>

<select id="selectMe">
    <option>

    </option>
</select>
</br>
<label>
    Make:
</label>
<select>
    <option>

    </option>
</select>
</br>
<label>
    Model:
</label>
<select>
    <option>

    </option>
</select>
</br>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
 function printIteration(){
var vehicleData = [{year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A4"},
    {year: 2014, make: "Benz", model: "c2000"},
    {year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "s-cross"},
    {year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "WagonR"}
];
for(var i = 0; i<vehicleData.length; i++){
    //console.log(vehicleData[i]);
    for( var i= 0; i<vehicleData.length; i++){
        //console.log(vehicleData[i].year);
        document.write(vehicleData[i].year + "</br>")
    }
}
}

 printIteration();

function buildDropdownYear(){
var yearSelect = document.getElementById("selectMe");
var drop1 = document.createElement("option");
yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);
var carYear = buildCtrl("data1","option");
}
buildDropdownYear();

function buildCtrl(data,ctrl){
var item = document.createElement(ctrl);
if(data){
    item.innerHTML = data;
}
return item;
}
```

I am new to javascript.I just started learning it I am kind of stuck in here because I am not getting what the error is. Console is showing this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.
yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);
```

My plunker is: http://plnkr.co/edit/fMufqCctzHe4Umbpu6Ag?p=preview

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why `document.write` ?

Comment: `var carYear = buildCtrl("data1", "option");` should be placed before `appendChild`.. You can not append `undefined`

Comment: And you should remove `document.write` as it will replace `DOM` with `written` content

Comment: ...and you are just passing `"data1"` string as your data. You should be passing the actual data from which you want to get the contents. In this case `vehicleData`.

Comment: yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);
var carYear = buildCtrl("data1","option");  how can u use a var carYear, before its being declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many issues in your code.

- Why do you want to create the `option` tag when it is already there
  in the `HTML`? Add it either in `HTML` or in `js`, not both.
- Also like others pointed out, you are trying to access a variable
  before even it is defined.
- One more problem I noticed is, you are not passing the data, that
  needs to be appended, but just a string `data1` as an argument to
  your function. You should pass the `vehicleData` array in your case.
- As a recommended alternative to `document.write` you could use DOM
  manipulation to directly query and add node elements to the DOM.

  Try to understand what you are trying to do. Take it one step at a time. Break your problems. You will get there. I have forked your Plunk and modified it so that the year value gets added to the dropdown. You can follow the same for other dropdown items.

  Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/739mzTUDafVLEXggZ9eO?p=preview).

Also consider the suggestions given in the comment section

```
 var vehicleData = [{year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A4"},
        {year: 2014, make: "Benz", model: "c2000"},
        {year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "s-cross"},
        {year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "WagonR"}
    ];


for(var i = 0; i<vehicleData.length; i++){
    buildDropdownYear(i);
}

function buildDropdownYear(k) {
    var yearSelect = document.getElementById("selectMe");
    var drop1 = document.createElement("option");

    var carYear = buildCtrl(k, vehicleData,"option");
    yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);
}

function buildCtrl(k, data,ctrl){
    var item = document.createElement(ctrl);
    if(data){
        item.innerHTML = data[k].year;
    }
    return item;
}
```

I wouldn't do it this way, If I were to begin with a fresh code. There is a lot of scope for improvements here.

Answer (score 0):

In `yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);` `carYear` is not being initialized.

`var carYear = buildCtrl("data1","option");` should come before the above line.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYbTyVOPjHQSTEsBZxab?p=preview)